# Супернеинтересный / супер неинтересный

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Я знаю, что *супер-* — это приставка, поэтому мы её должны вместе со словами писать так: *суперинтересный, суперигра, супермадмуазель, супервертолёт, суперэкстравагантный.*
Однако я не могу понять, писать ли *супернеинтересный* или же-с *супер неинтересный*. Можете мне в этом помочь?

Comment: Приставка "супер" имеет положительное значение. Поэтому выражение "супер*неинтересный" не имеет никакого смысла. А значит, и писать  никак не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слитно пишите, то есть ***супернеинтересный***. Это просто сухая орфография, сухое орфографическое правило о слитном написании префиксов с нарицательными существительными.

Общее прототипическое значение префикса супер — "высшая степень", "главенство", "превышение".

Другое дело, что в целом для русской деривации вроде как не очень характерно образование существительных с префиксом *супер* от слов с отрицательной приставкой *"не".*

Всё-таки несколько непривычно звучат гипотетические образования типа *невкусный - суперневкусный, немаловажный - супернемаловажный, незлой - супернезлой.*

Нельзя сказать, что это "неправильно", однако в базах текстов на русском язык (Корпус русского языка, Google Books и т. д.) таких образований почти нет.

Можно вашу мысль оформить не как одно слово, а как словосочетание, то есть значение "высшая степень" выразить не префиксом *супер*, а количественным наречием, примыкающим к прилагательному неинтересный, что кстати и характерно для русского языка.

Вместо супернеинтересный --> феноменально неинтересный, ужасающе неинтересный, весьма неинтересный, поразительно неинтересный, в высшей степени неинтересный и т. д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на правила. И почему: "о слитном написании префиксов с нарицательными существительными",  если это прилагательное.

Comment: Ссылка у Розенталя, Лопатина, в любом толковом и словообразовательном словаре. Все нарицательные имена существительные и прилагательные слитно пишутся с префиксами, кроме имён собственных и дериватов с -кое. Есть исключения типа экстра-класс и т. д., но супер- в их число не входит.

Comment: Это слово есть в словарях?  У Розенталя? Здесь принято давать ссылки на все источники. И что это за термин – сухая орфография? Писать надо строго по правилам. И это не ответ на заданный вопрос,  а просто рассуждение.  И обратите внимание – речь идет именно о прилагательных, а не о существительных.

Comment: Суперрозенталь - думаю, он бы оценил.

Comment: Я сам буду решать, как мне писать. Не рассказывайте мне, что тут принято, я на этом форуме пять лет.  Это первое. Второе, я сам буду выбирать, как мне отвечать на вопрос: будут и ссылки, и рассуждения, всё что угодно. В-третьих, вот ссылка на Лопатина: http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp117.php о написаниях с супер-. В-четвёртых, слова супернеинтересный в словарях нет , однако в русском языке есть деривация и  новые слова образуются каждый день.

Comment: Супер-Розенталь, вот как правильно.

Comment: Слово необычное,  у Лопатина таких примеров нет. Тогда обозначьте законы деривации, по которым можно образовать подобные слова. Кроме слитной формы, в р.я. есть еще раздельное и дефисное письмо. Должна же быть какая-то полезная информация в вашем ответе. Здесь дело даже не в конкретном слове, а в общем принципе такого особенного словообразования при наличии приставки НЕ в исходном слове. Стилистику опять же надо учитывать, область применения подобных оценочных слов. Желаю вам успеха в вашей работе.

Comment: Первое, чтобы говорить о стилистике и области применения, надо у автора просить, что это за текст и куда оно его хочет поместить: на стену сортира или в федеральный закон. Тогда и будет о чём говорить. Второе, я дал ссылку на справочник Лопатина по орфографии, это не толковый словарь, и там не может быть всех слов с супер-, особенно редких и образованных, например, вчера. Там общее правило о слитности нарицательных  имён с супер-. Написание супернеинтересный правилу не противоречит, а сообразно ему.

Comment: Что до деривации, то дериваты с супер от слов с "не" - штука, очевидно, редкая, но такую деривацию нельзя отрицать хотя бы потому, что автор вопроса употребил слово супернеинтересный в своей речи, и потому, что оно как минимум существует в его речи; кроме того, на просторах интернет при должном поиске можно найти и другие слова вида "супер + не". В твиттере и фейсбуке и т. д. А это значит, что этот словообразовательный тип, к примеру, ЗАРОЖДАЕТСЯ, что это потенциальный словообразовательный тип.

Comment: Также в языке есть окказионализмы, то есть авторские неологизмы, слова, образованные автором вот в этот момент и именно в этом тексте. Окказионализмы могут не отвечать словообразовательным типам русского языка, могут быть образованы с сознательным нарушением словообразовательных типов. Но никто не сможет оспорить авторскую неологию, отказать ей в существовании. Вот я считаю, что супернеинтересный, к примеру, окказионализм. Как писать его? Вот здесь можно обратиться к пратической кодификации от Лопатина и Розенталя с вышеуказаннй нормой о слитности супер- с нарицательными прилагательными.

Comment: Вообще-то законы деривации изучает грамматика, там и надо искать ответ на подобный вопрос.  И это не тема для справочника, там дается описание существующих слов. Автор же может написать любое слово, и оно будет авторским неологизмом, но это не предмет для изучения. А стилистика у этого слова в  оценочном значении может быть и  сниженной. Из словаря: супер2, неизм. (высшая оценка чего-н., сниж.) Но это при раздельном написании слова.

Comment: Когда частотность у слова буде достаточной., тогда и изучайте.

Comment: Шта, слово автора это не предмет изучения? Языкознание не должно изучать слова? Ха-ха-ха, лоооол, как говорится!

Comment: ЛОЛ, да? Некоторым нашим участникам нравится это слово...  Тогда, пожалуй, у меня больше вопросов к вам нет.

Comment: Супер2 в значении неизм. из лопатинского орфографического словаря - это супер как неизменяемое прилагательное! Используется как сказуемое: Фильм супер, конфеты просто супер! А супер в суперобложке и супернеинтересный - это морфема в составе слова.

Comment: Написание по аналогии? Такой метод может быть ошибочным. Что годится для одного, не подходит для другого.

Comment: Короче, вот автор спросил: как писать слово суперинтересный. Я говорю: смотри в кодификацию. В кодификации указано: префикс супер пишется слитно с нарицательными именными частями речи. Всё, ответ на вопрос дан.

Comment: Кто бы возражал... Если написан, то в любом случае дан.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала так: ***супер-неинтересный.***

**Обоснование**

1. Это слово вряд ли будет **нормировано правилами**, поэтому предлагается **авторское решение**. Подобных слов (при наличии приставки НЕ) практически  нет ни в словарях, ни в правилах, ни в текстах.

Поэтому речь идет о **возможности использования прилагательных** с приставкой НЕ в качестве **мотивирующего** слова.

А это **информация из словообразовательного словаря Ефремовой**: Приставка ***СУПЕР***- используется для образования прилагательных от прилагательных, **примыкая непосредственно к корню**: ***мощный – сверхмощный.*** Используется для образования слов, используемых в терминологии или публицистике.

Отсюда однозначно следует **НЕНОРМАТИВНОСТЬ словообразования и стилевой характеристики** для слова "сверхинтересный".

2. **Семантика:** очень неинтересный.
3. **Область применения**: разговорная речь,  социальные сети.
4. **Стилистика** сниженная, экспрессивная. **Частотность** употребления единичная.
5. Приставки могут писаться **слитно или через дефис.**

**Слитно**

Слитное написание нежелательно: графика выглядит не лучшим образом, понимание слова неясное, а это самый важный фактор в данном случае.

**Дефис**

Дефисная форма является промежуточной между раздельным и слитным написанием.

При дефисном написании ясно видны структура и значение слова.

Существительные  пишутся через дефис,  если иноязычный элемент имеет значение определения: *джаз-орестр, прима-балерина, гала-представление.*

Прилагательное: *контр-адмиральский.*

6. **Раздельное написание** (супер неинтересный) не соответствует правилам.

**Пример** использования в речи: *Эта книга для меня  – неинтересная! Даже более того, она **супер-неинтересная**! Ни сюжета, ни характеров...*

**Примеры слов** с двумя дефисами: [http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=Супер-&start=15](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-&start=15)

Answer (score 1):

Супер - это не приставка, супер - это корень. Получается сложносоставное слово по типу матчасть. Матнечасть - не говорят и не выдумывают. Говорят или не суперинтересный, или... математическая не часть - тоже не говорят. То есть слово из нескольких корней не разбивают префиксами, потому что тогда дичь получится, суффикс можно прибавить колхозный.

Хотя, можно иногда написать просто отдельное слово:

Математический нечастный. Но тогда это будет две различные характеристики чего-то, не связанные между собой. То есть он - супер и он - неинтересный. Хотя тут можно выдумать другое слово - гипер, которая не положительное, а вообще превосходство, не превосходящее по отношению чего-то.

Он - гипер неинтересный=он запредельно неинтересный.

Хотя, в английском супер(хотя это по сути тоже, что и гипер и скорее всего это одно и тоже слово) может использоваться с отрицательными приставками:

super+im+pose - супер+не-ожиданно, в негативном ключе. Хотя в русском есть еще слово весьма, которое в целом выполняет те же функции: весьма неожиданно. Хотя тут не прилагательное. А verb по английски, и я затрудняюсь в подборе глагола, если честно) - супернеожидать? super+im+pose+ed - супернеожидал.) А вот весьма не ожидал не создает диссонанса, и не с глаголами как бы раздельно)

Добавлю еще например, вкусный - по сути уже слово с приставкой В+кус. Вкусный - уже вкусное. Супервкусный - ну это немного как плеоназм? С другой стороны не вкусной - это гадкий. Супергадкий - вполне звучит. То есть супер - не обязательно положительная значимая приставка, а в виду того, что она не сочетается с другими приставками, скорее всего это таки корень.